# Make BufferedReader start from the middle of a .txt file rather than the beginning?

Tags: java, android

I have a LONG .txt file that contains almost 6000 lines! Sometimes I need to retrieve the info. in line 5000.  Is it possible to start reading from line 5000 rather than starting from the beginning?

Thanks.

Comment: In Java, 6000 lines isn't long enough to worry about. It won't save you much time as the biggest cost is accessing the disk at all. ~ 10 ms. Everything else is small by comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether 6000 lines are long or not depends on the average line length. Even with 100 characters per line, this is not really long.

Nevertheless, you can read from line 5000 if you know where line 5000 starts. Unfortunately, most of the time you'll have to read lines 1 through 4999 to find that out.

Comment: There are fixed positions I want to start to get the text from, eg: Lines:  1 to 7 , 8 to 300 , 301 to 500 ...  So I was wondering if there was a way to start from a position..

Comment: @Omar, read Peter's comment above. Just go through this smallish file line by line. Although one can position a file at a given byte offset, there is no easy way to calculate a byte offset from a line number - even if each line has the same length in characters, you still do not know how many bytes this are.

Answer (score 2):

As 5000 lines is not so big, and it will do a sequential file access, this simple idea could work:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileName));
for (int i = 0; i < 5000 && in.ready; in.readLine()) { }
if (in.ready()) {
  // you are at line 5000;
} else {
  // the file is smaller than 5000 lines
}
```

Another idea is to use the bufferedRead.skip(n) method, but for it every line should have the same length. By example, each line having 100 characters, you will need to do:

```
int ls = System.getProperty("line.separator").length();
in.skip((100 + ls) * 5000);
```

Comment: The lines arent the same length.. I will use the first solution then, I though that reading from 5000 lines is enormous!.. Thanks.

Comment: If they are the same size, the BufferedRead skip will work well, just do not forget the line separator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a skip method for the BufferedReader in java, which allows you to skip x characters. To get to a specific line is much harder though.

Edit: [Found it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip%28long%29)

Comment: The length of the lines isnt fixed so that wont help me =\

Comment: That's what I thought. If the text file is a log or something similar where the first 4999 lines don't change then it might be worth caching (if thats the right word to use) the position of the 5000th line, and reading it fully if the cache isn't built.