# Printing last 200 lines from Logcat

Tags: java, android

I am trying to print the last 200 or so lines from Android Logcat in my app.
So far I have been able to get Logcat into a BufferedReader using InputStreamReader. The problem is I don't know how to to jump to the end of the buffered Reader and then read backwards, Or jump to a just above the last 200 lines and print from there.
I don't want to do the brute force method where I read the whole log. I am hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you convert the contents of the BufferedReader to something like an ArrayList, then jump to ArrayList.length() - 200, and print the items from that point until ArrayList.length() in a loop?

Comment: I could but that would involve going through the whole buffer and putting each line into the Array

Comment: "I don't want to do the brute force method where I read the whole log."  .. I should have considered that first, my apologies.

Comment: It appears from the accepted answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855716/make-bufferedreader-start-from-the-middle-of-a-txt-file-rather-than-the-beginni) that you may not be able to do this with a BufferedReader.  Is there any other way you can store the LogCat?

Comment: LogCat can only be read using an inputStream.

Comment: @UmarGhulam Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should write your solution as an answer and remove it from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't the solution I was looking for but does what I wanted. Instead of bringing the log into a BufferedReader and then sorting it out and printing it. I use logcat tags to specific the size of an output file.

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("logcat -r 160 -f mylog.log")
```

And then reading back the file.

Answer (score 2):

A BufferedReader doesn't know the concept of a line, only stream of data. You'll have a hard time finding a way to jump to (EOF - 200 lines) if you don't know how long a line even is.

I'd recommend stuffing a RingBuffer after it, storing 200 lines with newest replacing the oldest ones. That way the BufferedReader keeps on filling the ringBuffer and you use that to read.

another alternative would be clearing the log every 200 lines...

Comment: What a cool data structure. I have never heard of this before and it is a perfect fit for this exact thing. Good idea.