# Reading a txt file using multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read few answers regarding reading a file using multithreading and also found that its efficiency is very poor but still for the sake of learning I am trying to read a file using multithreading i.e for a large file few records should be read by one thread and other by another one.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QueueThread implements Runnable {

    int count=0;
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public QueueThread(int start,int end) {
        this.start=start;
        this.end=end;


    }

    public void run() {

        for(int i=start;i<end;i++) {        

        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("userinfo.txt"));
            read.useDelimiter(",|\n");
            String mobile,recharge;

            while(read.hasNext())
            {                
              mobile = read.next();
              recharge =read.next();

              ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
              words.add(mobile+recharge);

              count++;

              System.out.println("mobile no.:"+ mobile);
              System.out.println("recharge amount:"+ recharge);
              System.out.println("count:"+ count );
            }

            read.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Control.java:

```
public class Control {  
     public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {  
         QueueThread r1=new QueueThread(0,15); 
         QueueThread r2=new QueueThread(15,30);
          Thread t1 =new Thread(r1);
          Thread t2 =new Thread(r2);

          t1.start();
          t2.start();

          t1.join();
          t2.join();


    }
}
```

Here I am reading a file userinfo.txt with some random 10 digits no. and some number. Each thread reads the whole file rather than just reading the first 15 entries in one thread and other 14 entries in another thread which I believe defeats my motto of reading file in parallel.
I am also trying to store the extracted data in ArrayList for performing further operations on it.

**userinfo.txt**

```
9844794101,43
9844749102,54  
9844741903,55 
9844741094,33 
9844741095,87
9844741068,32 
9844974107,53
8848897101,343 
8848891702,345
8848891063,34
8848849104,64
```

I am really need some way out to read the file simultaneously in different thread

**current output**

```
mobile no.:9844794101
recharge amount:43
mobile no.:9844794101
count:1
recharge amount:43
count:1
mobile no.:9844749102
recharge amount:54  
mobile no.:9844749102
recharge amount:54  
count:2
count:2
```

And so on

Comment: I have no idea why there are so many questions about multithreaded read recently (look at the related questions to the right). There is usually not much to gain because the I/O hardware (disk, data bus, ...) is the bottleneck and not the CPU.

Comment: For the sake of learning *what*? You can read millions of lines per second in a single thread. What exactly are you expecting to gain, even intellectually, by partiioning the problem into threads?

Comment: If you want to learn about multi-threading, reading a relatively tiny file is not the right problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for the sake of learning, then just use a single Scanner object by your two threads. Since you need to read a pair of adjacent words and then join them, you'll have to think of some solution how to make your two threads work.

The simplest way is to allow every thread read a couple of words using 'synchronized(scannerObject) {...}. Of course, the performance would be worse than a single-threaded solution. Other solutions might avoid synchronization, e.g. if you use AtomicInteger as a counter and store the words in ConcurrentSkipListMap from a counter to the next word.

I think the classic approach is to know a precise point in a middle of a file from which you could read a new word. Then your first thread would read a file from start to the 'middle' position, and the second thread could read from the 'middle' position to the end. See e.g. [Make BufferedReader start from the middle of a .txt file rather than the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855716/make-bufferedreader-start-from-the-middle-of-a-txt-file-rather-than-the-beginni)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("userinfo.txt"));
```

you need to use something like

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("userinfo.txt"))));
inputStream.skip(<number of bytes to start of first desired record>);
Scanner read = new Scanner(inputStream);
// then make sure you only read as many records as you need
```

Search for more information about `InputStream`s and `Reader`s.

The problem is, given your record format, there is no way to get the correct argument to `skip` without reading the previous part of the file (though you only need to look for newlines, not for `,` or `|`). You could make `start` and `end` number of bytes instead of number of records, but then you need to be aware you are likely to land in the middle of a record and be careful.

Also, if you want the final `ArrayList` to be in order, then the second thread will have to wait until the first thread is done inserting. If you don't, make sure to synchronize access to it or use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html instead.